# How to filter/parse string of html templates with plain javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, templates

I have a string of html templates, each wrapped in script tag with id-s.

Example templates string:

```
<script id="id1"> some html </script>
<script id="id2"> some other html </script>
```

I want to find template in this string with specified id and get html template without wrapper script tag. 
Here is jquery approach to this problem that works:

```
var template = $(templates).filter("#id1").html();
```

Unfortunately I need to do the same thing in plain javascript, but I can't find a simple solution to this problem. How can I do this without jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var template = `<script id='id1' src="" /><script id='id2' src="" / >`;

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = template;
var filterElement = div.querySelectorAll("#id1");

console.log(filterElement[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

With javascript, you can get a a DOM node by id using

```
document.getElementById("ID_GOES_HERE")
```

So, in your case, I would try something like

```
let tmplt = document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML;
```

or

```
let tmplt = document.getElementById("id1").innerText;
```

Read more about dom elements [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp).

Also, on a side note, let is probably better to use then var, as it has better scoping, but in the above code I wrote, let could be substituted with var

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, Templates is a string and is not part of the document, that's why I can not use getElementById to retrieve the "node" which in my case is substring of Templates-string.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can do this by using Regular Expressions.
[This website](https://regexr.com/) may help you to find the right one.